# Python - Selenium wrong url or server out of reach

Tags: python, selenium, exception

How to handle url exceptions. If user enter a wrong url or the server does not response

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
browser.get('http://www.abc.abc/')
```

I am using python. Program does not throw error if url is wrong or server out of reach

Answer (score 1):

How to handle any exception example

```
try:
    browser.get('http://www.abc.abc/')
except Exception as e:
    print("except -> browser.get -> %s" %e)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to check for and handle the wrong URL errors you could do something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
browser.get('http://www.abc.sdfd/')

try:
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('error-code')
    print('Error')
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('No error')
```